# Set dynamic range in Custom Formula Data Validation using Google Sheets API

Tags: validation, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am using [GoogleSheets Api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) to set Data Validation using Custom Formula to reject negative and decimal values on specific columns for example (E,F) and rows can vary depending on data. All this has been defined in range property.

While writing custom formula, we need to define cell value. Right now, I have hardcoded E3 in formula. Is there any way how can I achieve it dynamically or pass range?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
                setDataValidation: {
                    range: {
                        sheetId: 0,
                        startRowIndex: 2,
                        endRowIndex: rowsLength(variable),
                        startColumnIndex: 4,
                        endColumnIndex: 6
                    },
                    rule: {
                        condition: {
                            type: "CUSTOM_FORMULA",
                            values: [
                                {
                                    userEnteredValue: "=AND(int(E3)=E3, E3>0)"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        inputMessage: "Please enter a non decimal numeric value greater than zero",
                        strict: true
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for, but I'd say you just need to interpolate the variable:

```
userEnteredValue: "=AND(int(" + range + ")=" + range + ", " + range + ">0)"
```

Where `range` is a variable with the A1 notation of the range, for example, `range = "E3"`.

#### Note:

- Don't know which language you're using, depending on which you could use different interpolation methods.

Comment: I m using node for configuration. Problem is with getting the alphabetic notation as I know the index value. Either I have to create a map of alphabets with index value or if there is any other solution.
Also, range will accept single value. What if I need to apply formula for E3:K3, how should it be handled

Comment: @KajalArora Could you please share a sample spreadsheet containing the desired outcome? It could be very useful to find a solution to your issue, since I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to accomplish.